# Remove low value rows for each ID

Tags: r

I have a data with three variables, and I want to keep the id rows with high “value”, and remove the rows with low “value” for each id.

What I have

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), case=c("a","b","c","c","b","a","b","c","c","a","b","c","c","a","b","c","a","b"), value=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
```

What I need

```
    id case value
4   1   c   2
5   1   b   2
8   2   c   2
9   2   c   2
10  3   a   2
11  3   b   2
17  4   a   2
18  4   b   2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
    mydata[mydata$value==ave(mydata$value,mydata$id,FUN=max),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata[mydata$value>1,]
```

or

```
mydata[mydata$value>min(mydata$value),]
```

Comment: This won’t work, because may be some ids have a single value of 1 and no 2’s, in that case I need to keep them. Also, in my data, the numbers are different than 1 and 2…